# How do I use function from same module?

Tags: javascript

Below is my example, i create a .js file let other .js file can use it as a Helper.

```
var Helper = {
    print: function() {
        console.log("test");
    },

    show: function() {
        print();
    }
}

module.exports = Helper;
```

In other .js file I can include Helper file like below

```
 var Helper = require('./Helper.js');
 Helper.print(); // i will get "test" on console.
```

However, if I do like blow, it cannot find print function in same Helper file.

```
 var Helper = require('./Helper.js');
 Helper.show();
```

What can I do to use functions which from same Helper js file?

Comment: use `this.print();` in Helper.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have anything to do with modules or files.

The function is stored on a property of an object. It isn't an in-scope variable.

You need to either:

1. Refer to the object (`this.print()`) (see also [How does the `this` keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work))
2. Make it an in-scope variable

Such:

```
function print() {
    console.log("test");
};

var Helper = {
    print: print
    show: function() {
        print();
    }
}

module.exports = Helper;
```